# Domain Access with URL Alias - same content, but with different automated aliases

Tags: 6, domain-access, path-aliases

I have a site running Domain Access with two domains - the primary domain and the sub-domain. Both domains share the same content in the database, but I would like the automated URL aliases for the sub-domain to be different from that of the primary domain's.

There are two tables in the database right now - the `url_alias` table and the `domain_2_url_alias` table (of which the latter is a copy of the original `url_alias` table).

I tried modifying the settings under `/admin/build/path/pathauto` and selected the sub-domain under the "Save settings for:" option, but that didn't seem to have any effect at all.

I can change the values in domain_2_url_alias manually for each node (which worked), but the site generates new content very often, that this wouldn't be a viable solution.

I appreciate any help I can get! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is exactly what the [Domain Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_path) module is for.

According to the module page:

> The Domain Path module allows the creation of separate path aliases per domain for nodes created using the Domain Access module.

However, it looks like this module provides the option per node, rather than offering different pathauto patterns which I think is what you want. There's a [postponed request in the issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1310628) for pathauto integration that offers a partial patch, but it's offered as an anti-proof-of-concept, it seems.

Comment: Excerpt or quote from module's page would be appropriate.

Comment: I've checked out that module, and it doesn't seem to have any sort of documentation---at least not from what I found. Does anyone know of any documentation on how to configure Domain Path?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kelley! I also found the same patch, but was not sure if there was another patch or module already out there - since there wasn't any confirmation in that thread as to if it worked or not. I'll keep looking and if I come up with an alternate solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks Molot. I updated my response accordingly (but didn't have enough rep to leave a comment until now!)